# Backup in process but no data being copied

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, permissions, backup

I am performing a backup of a site collection in SharePoint 2010. The operation begins and shows on the Job Status screen as Operation in Progress and a .bak file is created in the folder I specified on the application server.

So far so good, however, When I browse the folder in question the .bak file is showing a size of 0Kb and not getting any larger. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: how big the site is? and how long the job is running?

Comment: The site is just over 400Gb, so double the recommended size. When I went home this evening the job had been running uninterrupted for about an hour with no errors appearing in the event log.

Comment: 400 Gb is huge site you have to wait for longer time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 GB is really huge site collection, it is really hard to backup it.

- I would recommend go for the Content Database backup instead of Site collection backup, as it will take too much time.
- I am afraid, your browser may be timed out which again hurt the process. So try to use the PowerShell BAckup-SPsite command and test your luck.

On side note, please split your site collection as it is already out of control from management stand point.